# Why is my reactive data property undefined?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a response from an api which is stored inside topic_data. I want to use the property of the said object inside another api but because i can use it I console logged it, it gave me undefined, I'm confused.

This is the method where the topic_data was stored. Note: The fetchData method was ran using mounted lifecycle method

```js
async fetchData() {
    try {
        this.fetchingdata = true;
        const id = await this.get_id(this.$route.params['topic_id'])

        const response = await this.$axios.$post("/topic_info", {topic_id: id});
        this.content_data = response.content
      this.topic_data = response.topic;
        console.log(this.topic_data+ " fetch");


      this.topic = response.topic['title'];
      //this.topic_id = response.topic['id'];
        console.log(this.topic_data.id+ " topic")
```

It is stored in the data method up ahead, like this

```js
topic_data: {},
```

I'm trying to make use of it here in the post method, I console logged it above it gave me undefined

```js
async getNote() {
  //const id = await this.get_id(this.$route.params['topic_id'])
   //console.log(id);
    console.log(this.topic_id+ " my topic id")
      try {
      this.fetchingdata = true;
      const response =  await this.$axios.$post("/all_topic_notes", {
        topic_id: this.topic_data.id,
      })
      console.log(response)
      console.log(this.total_note+ "all topic notes")
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message+" error")
    }
  },
```

How can I see the information and use them inside the topic_data?

Comment: are you sure its `$axios.$post` and not `$axios.post`?

Comment: I'm using $axios.$post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually to get the response from `axios` you'd access the `data` property so you'd have something like

```js
const response = await this.$axios.$post("/topic_info", {topic_id: id});
const response_data = response.data;
this.content_data = response_data.content; // assuming you have a property called `content` here
```

Comment: You are correct, but I want to reuse the topic_data property somewhere else, it's saying undefined